# How to fix: "Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created." warning

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

Anytime I try to plot anything with Matplotlib I get this warning.

> *Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created.*

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Tried googling any issues related to Qt bindings in Matplotlib - still couldn't fix this.

Here is a simple code that would yield the warning

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.arange(1000) # the distribution doesn't matter
plt.hist(a) # here could plt.scatter or plt.plot - would still get same error.
plt.show()
```

Comment: It should be fixed by [#14566](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/14566). Which version of matplotlib are you using? Are you running this code in IPython or as a script?

Comment: this [upgrading to Matplotlib 3.1.1] solved the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be solved by updating matplotlib to the latest version. First, remove the older version using:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
```

Then, install the latest version using:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Comment: or simply `pip install -U matplotlib` (`-U` is a shorthand for `--upgrade`)

Answer (score 6):

in QT you have some rules when setting application flags, and that is one of them,

you need to do something like (c++ as ref but in python is the same):

```
//first set the flags
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
//more code and then create the QApplication 
QApplication mainApplication(argc, argv);
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise this thread has been dormant for some time, however for the benefit of those like me who are stuck (for various reasons well beyond the scope of this question) on python 2.7, doing the following also stops the warning:
Edit the backend_qt5.py file under site-packages/matplotlib/backends, and in the create_qApp() function, move the final few qApp.setAttribute lines into an earlier loop. The original function looks like this:

```
def _create_qApp():
    """
    Only one qApp can exist at a time, so check before creating one.
    """
    global qApp

    if qApp is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
        if app is None:
            # check for DISPLAY env variable on X11 build of Qt
            if is_pyqt5():
                try:
                    from PyQt5 import QtX11Extras
                    is_x11_build = True
                except ImportError:
                    is_x11_build = False
            else:
                is_x11_build = hasattr(QtGui, "QX11Info")
            if is_x11_build:
                display = os.environ.get('DISPLAY')
                if display is None or not re.search(r':\d', display):
                    raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable')

            qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication([b"matplotlib"])
            qApp.lastWindowClosed.connect(qApp.quit)
        else:
            qApp = app

    if is_pyqt5():
        try:
            qApp.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)
            qApp.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

and the edited function is this:

```
def _create_qApp():
    """
    Only one qApp can exist at a time, so check before creating one.
    """
    global qApp

    if qApp is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
        if app is None:
            # check for DISPLAY env variable on X11 build of Qt
            if is_pyqt5():
                try:
                    from PyQt5 import QtX11Extras
                    is_x11_build = True
                except ImportError:
                    is_x11_build = False
                try:
                    qApp.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)
                    qApp.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
                except AttributeError:
                    pass


            else:
                is_x11_build = hasattr(QtGui, "QX11Info")
            if is_x11_build:
                display = os.environ.get('DISPLAY')
                if display is None or not re.search(r':\d', display):
                    raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable')

            qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication([b"matplotlib"])
            qApp.lastWindowClosed.connect(qApp.quit)
        else:
            qApp = app

    #if is_pyqt5():
     #   try:
     #       qApp.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)
     #       qApp.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
     #   except AttributeError:
     #       pass
```

Perhaps there are neater ways of hacking the matplotlib libraries but this worked well enough for me.